# SP_Who does not return DBName Column

Tags: sql-server, delphi, odbc, bde

My Delphi application connects to a SQL Server Database through BDE.
In the process, my application queries `SP_Who` stored procedure to get the DbName column Value. But now I want to connect my application through ODBC to the SQL Server database.

I'm using the SQL Server Native client driver for this, but when my application queries `SP_Who` but the procedure does not return the DBName Column.  Why is this? How can I get the value of DBName in this case?  Is there any other procedure to obtain the DBName column value.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the database name using:

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

Do you get the DBName column running `sp_who2` ?

Comment: No I dont Ge DBName Column running sp_who2 either. The Select DB_NAME() dosent work too. It returns a blank column.

Comment: @SK9: sounds like it might be permissions related.

Comment: @SK9: what identity and role are in running under?

Comment: @SK9: SELECT DB_NAME() *has* to return a value. You always have a database context, even if it's master. Do you get any rows back from sp_who? Try SELECT @@SERVERNAME

Comment: I dont think this is a problem with the Databse rights or permissons, coz when I connect to the sane Database using BDE alias all the above commands Work. It seems they only dont give any value, when i connect trough the ODBC Connection. Am i  missing some settings in creating the ODBC connection.

Comment: some how still when i use ODBC Sql server native client  i dont get the DBname when i  query sp_who. Infact i dont get the loginame field when i query the sys.sysprocesses. But I do get the DBID field which i used in this situation. This is a mere workaround to get my application up and running.